# Android app - How to take text entered on the app and enter into a textbox on a website

Tags: java, android, text, input, transfer

I am making an android app and I want to make it so the users can enter text into a text input box. When a button is clicked, this text is taken from the input box on the app and entered into a text box on another website.

Is this possible to do? If so, what do I need to use in order to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: there is an ambiguity in your question.when user enter some text you want to transfer that text to a website and wanna show there ???

Comment: I want the user to enter text into a text box on the app. When they click a button I want this text in the text box on the app to be transferred to another text box on a website (the user will not see this happening). I am basically trying to create a log in page on my app via a website (we do not have access to their database). Thanks for getting back to me!